# How to hint python3.6 that parameter must be sized and iterable both?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

I have a function that requires parameter to be both Sized and Iterable at the same time.

```
def foo(items):
    print(len(items))
    for i in item:
        print(i)
```

I thought that I can use standard `typing` module from python3.5+ and write this:

```
from  typing import Collection, Any

def foo(items: Collection[Any]):
    print(len(items))
    for i in item:
        print(i)



foo([1, 2, 3])
# PyCharm warns: Expected type 'Collection', got 'List[int]' instead.
```

[Collection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Collection) looks like what I need:  `class typing.Collection(Sized, Iterable[T_co], Container[T_co])`

**Why it causes warning?**

**What should i do to hint parameter as both Iterable and Sized?**

Comment: `Collection` is indeed sized and iterable (see also [the `abc` version](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Collection)); this could be a bug in PyCharm or whatever plugin it uses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Collection` was only introduced in 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Collection); odds are, your version of PyCharm doesn't recognize it yet.

There is no built-in that describes a sized, iterable container in 3.5, so you can't use this annotation in 3.5, at least, not without writing your own `typing` type, which PyCharm may or may not recognize.

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard, indeed it is. I had to check youtrack first.

Comment: Could you suggest how to join Sized and Iterable in my own Type?

Comment: @AlexanderChzhen: Easiest way would be to borrow the code from [Python 3.6's `collections.abc`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/_collections_abc.py#L388) and [`typing` module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/typing.py#L1812) (qualifying names as needed) to make your own `Collection` ABC and `Collection` typing hint class. Copying the code would rely on implementation details, so you'd want to write code that tries to get `typing.Collection`, and only falls back to defining it using implementation details if you get an `ImportError`.

Answer (score 0):

A dirty fix to make Python 3.5 happy is to use `Union[Sized, Iterable[Any]]`.

It is dirty, because using this type annotation says that it should be either sized OR iterable, not sized AND iterable.
The current Pycharm (2018.1) accepts this, and it runs.

---

**UPDATE:**
I have found a way to use `Collections` in Python versions < 3.6.
Before 3.6 `Sequence` is basically what `Collection` is in 3.6 (See [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/typing.html#typing.Sequence) and [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/typing.html#typing.Collection)). In 3.6 a `Sequence` is basically a reversible `Collection` (see [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/typing.html#typing.Sequence)), and this gave me issues, because a python `set` is not a sequence (it is not reversible) so I patched it with the following import code:

```
if sys.version_info >= (3, 6):
    from typing import Collection
else:
    from typing import Sequence, TypeVar

    T = TypeVar('T')
    Collection = Sequence[T]
```